# Testing In App Purchases Currency & Price on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test In app purchase with different currency and price. Right now it always show me in INR. I changed my device country as USA. Also changed my Apple ID country to USA. Still it shows price in INR. Apple rejected app because they are getting error pop up saying price and currency is null. The screenshot they sent shows In app purchase price in USD. So I want to replicate my issue and want to debug In app purchase price in USD.

So, my question is how to get. In app purchase price in USD while testing from India ?

Below is my code to get Price from StoreKit.

```
SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([value]) { result in
        if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
            let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
            
            print("Product: \(product.price) \(product.localizedDescription), price: \(priceString)")
            Loader.shared.stopAnimatingLoader()
            responseHandler(product.localizedPrice!,Int(truncating: product.price), true)
```

I have also tried below code to get price information from SkProduct but it gives in local currency instead of USD.

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
                let formattedPrice = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price)
```

Comment: Could you show your code for fetching and displaying the price?

Comment: Added code in question.

Comment: You should not be using the product price directly, as in the last line. You must use the product priceLocale to pass the price through a NumberFormatter and use only the resulting string.

Comment: Ok let me try with NumberFormatter and will get back to you

Comment: Well presumably that is what SwiftyStoreKit does to get the localised price. But in your code you also get price directly as a number; that’s wrong.

Comment: I have tried with NumberFormatter and that does the same thing what my code do. But still the question is I want USD price from India. I am getting this in Locale.<__NSCFLocale: 0x600003b02990> 'en_IN@currency=INR'}
Printing description of formattedPrice:
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "₹ 749.00"

Comment: I agree, the question of how to test is a good question!